# Most efficient way to assign different things to objects made from the class?

Tags: python, class

I come across problems like this a lot, but here's an example.

Let's say I'm making a main menu for a game. There are 5 buttons, **play, settings, level select, tutorial,** and **more from this developer**. I want to use the same class for each of these buttons. Each of them will have different text to display, positions, and colors. I could do the time consuming if statements, but is there any faster way?

```
def __init__(self):
    self.button=button
    if self.button=="play":
        self.text="play"
    elif self.button=="settings":
        self.text="settings"

     #and so on...
```

The method I've been using right now is lists.

```
text=["play","settings","tutorial"]
colors=[black,white,red]

for i in range(3):
    button=button_class()
    button.text=text[i]
    button.color=colors[i]
```

It's been working pretty good, but I still haven't done anything that involves a lot more specific data for each class. I was wondering if anyone has any insight on this? This is Python after all, I'm confident there's a simple solution to this. Oh and if it's any help, I'm using pygame.

Comment: Create the `Button` with the `text`, `color` and `action` as attributes in `__init__`

Comment: Can I see an example to what you are trying to say?

Comment: Maybe you're not such a bad coder. At least you ask the right questions. Some developers do consider the first code example as completely normal :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use

```
buttons = [button_class("play", black),
           button_class("settings", white),
           button_class("tutorial", red)]
```

To achieve that, `__init__` needs to be like:

```
def __init__(self, text:str, color):
    self.text = text
    self.color = color
```

---

Code like

```
def __init__(self):
    self.button=button
    if self.button=="play":
        self.text="play"
    elif self.button=="settings":
        self.text="settings"
```

violates the OCP ([Open Closed Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle)) of clean code. That class would require modification whenever you want to add a new button. OCP says that a class should be closed for modification, but still be open for extension.

With the example I posted above, you can still create a lot of different buttons ("open"), but there's no need to change the button class itself ("closed").

---

The code

```
text=["play","settings","tutorial"]
colors=[black,white,red]

for i in range(3):
    button=button_class()
    button.text=text[i]
    button.color=colors[i]
```

Is indeed already better, but IMHO violates the KISS principle ([Keep it simple, stupid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)).

In that piece of code, the developer needs to ensure that `text` and `color` always have the same number of elements and that the `for` loop has the correct range.

In the example I posted above, you can hardly get things wrong without the IDE complaining beforehand.

Comment: Oh I didn't know you could do this! I won't have to do the ```for i in range(3)``` stuff then right?

Comment: This is very basic object instantiation stuff.  You should never have an if statement as you describe in an init (or any other function).  The class should have attributes that change the behaviors of different objects of the class.

Comment: @bad_coder: exactly. The buttons are already initialized then. Maybe you need a `for button in buttons:` loop somewhere in order to make the buttons known to pygame